# Which of the following sentences are correct grammatically?

Tags: grammar, american-english

Which of the following sentences are correct?

And please explain to me the meaning of each sentence. Why correct? Or Why wrong?

1. I give you money.
2. I give money you.
3. I give money to you.

Comment: (1) and (3) are different ways of saying the same thing - both correct. (2) is incorrect (I can't tell you why, it's just not how we say it in English).

Comment: I personally sometimes say ***Give it me***, but that's probably down to me "swallowing / failing to articulate" the preposition in the full form *Give it **to** me*, rather than an actual "resequencing" as per your example #2. Which as @Kate says is "incorrect".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yes, I wondered whether to mention constructions such as "I'll give it you tomorrow", but decided to keep things simple!

Comment: I'm a Southerner, and I don't think I've often if ever heard this direct/indirect object inversion from my peers down south. I picked it up from my Lancastrian father - so noting that you're in Derby, I wonder if it's [primarily?] a Northern British usage (I find it hard to imagine hearing ***Give it me**!* in an American accent). I also note that only a few *specific* combinations of objects (always *pronouns*?) and tenses seem to work. I'm sure you agree with me that we *can't* say ***I gave the book John yesterday*** with no preposition.